# What is the best approach to creating message models in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about javascript best practice. I am trying to create a *message model* in javascript. Means my whole application messages (popover message, tooltip message, error message, warning message etc) should be at one place. So for this i decided to create an anonymous object in javascript like this:

```
var Message = {
    ForFirstView: {
        Popover: {
            FirstPopover: {
                Message: function (param) {
                    return 'Message with' + param;
                }
            },
            SecondPopover: {
                Message: function (param) {
                    return 'Message with' + param;
                }
            }
            ..... 
            ........
        },
        Tooltip: {
            FirstName: {
                Message: function (param) {
                    return 'Your first name is this with ' + param;
                }
            },
            LastName: {
                Message: function (param) {
                    return 'Your last name is this with ' + param;
                }
            },
            Email: {
                Message: function (param) {
                    return 'Your email is this with ' + param;
                }
            }
            ......
            .........
        }
    },
    ForSecondView: {
        FileTypeNotSupported: function (file) {
            return 'This ' + file + ' not supported.'
        },
        Camera: {
            Stopped: "Your web cam stopped."
        }
        .....
        ......
    }
    ............
    ..............
};
```

Now if i want to show the message in *first popover* of *first view* than i can do :

```
Message.ForFirstView.Popover.FirstPopover.Message('anyvalue');
```

By this my all messages come at one place, so future edits and updates becomes easy.

But i want to know the advise of yours about this Message model. Or if there is any other better approach to handle this than please let me know about that.

This question arises in my mind because when i am creating a documentation for this message model (Using [yuidoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/)) than i cant figure out how to document this (*because of multilevel hierarchy*). So please suggest me the way for better documentation also for this message model if this model is good enough to continue.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just wanting to use this for validation? There are plenty of validation libraries out there.

Comment: Can't you just use an array of objects instead of explicitly naming it `firstpopover`, `secondpopover`, etc. and just reference them using the indexes? Eg. `Message[0].Popover[0].message`

Comment: Take a look at [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) for Javascript

Comment: theres nothing to document about `this` as its just an ref to the window object(unless you are using `call`/`apply` somewhere)  and never used

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is a good thing. It's always good to have organization like this. You might consider using shorter names, because it's just easier and faster in the long run. When I start building a new front end, I'll have at least several files like this, but not just for functions but also useful scalars, constants, and associative arrays that might be of use for the project. And then I attach each file to one global namespace for the web app. So I'll have, for example, MyApp.Messaging, MyApp.Config, and MyApp.DateTime, etc.

You mention "model," so I'll say, there are a ton of front end MVC libraries such as Backbone, Ember, Knockout, etc. that give you a framework to build within -- and by using their methodologies you can leverage what those libraries have to offer while keeping your code organized. However, there is a (sometimes steep) learning curve with those libraries, and they're certainly not necessary to building a great front end.

I think what you might look into more is how to write object-oriented javascript. The [jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide1) is an easy way to create, for example, message objects that you can use and reuse for various types of popups, dialogs, and alerts that you might need for your website. Or coffeescript allows you to write classes instead of prototypes, which you might find more appealing. You could use your Message model above in conjunction with a few dialog/window/modal classes, and you would have a robust, organized messaging system for your web app.